# Auto-login sometimes fails

Tags: 12.04, auto-login

Running Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit, 3.8.0-31-generic

Occasionally, perhaps 33%, on bootup, I get my MDM manual login screen and need to enter username/password, even though I've configured mdmsetup for auto-login.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

Root-caused the issue to a corrupted package installation of plymouth.

First, need to update mountall:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dtl131/mediahacks
sudo update
```

Next, remove plymouth and install it:

```
sudo apt-get purge plymouth
sudo apt-get install plymouth
```

Don't forget to remove the repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:dtl131/mediahacks
```

Next issue I ran into was I had the text-only boot splash screen instead of the lovely Ubuntu graphical logo.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```

Follow this fix and I'm booting like a champ with flawless auto-login and graphical Ubuntu splash screen:

http://jechem.blogspot.com/2011/04/fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-ubuntu-on.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems kludgy, but by adding the following line to my /etc/mdm/mdm.conf, this sporadic nagging issue seems to have gone away (10+ consecutive bootups with clean automatic login):

```
/etc/mdm/mdm.conf
[daemon]
TimedLoginEnable=true
TimedLogin=frustratedUser
TimedLoginDelay=0
```

Comment: If there are any Ubuntu gurus out there who know what the real issue is here (some sort of startup ordering issue perhaps?) that requires this hokey workaround, I'd love to hear about it...